# textfield with description label inside

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I am working with swift 4 for macOS and I would like to know, if a description label into a textfield is possible?

Something like this:

[image]

"Start:" should be the description label and "My text" the text, which I type into the textfield.

If this is possible: How can i realize it?

Comment: You should use placeholderString. Note that it will disappear when user starts typing. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfield/1399391-placeholderstring

Comment: yes, but this is not what I would like to realize :(

Comment: You shouldn't try to change how the user interface behaviours. Use it as it is.

Comment: This will confuse the user. I would try to select "Start". But if you really want to do this, put two borderless text fields inside a white box.

Comment: "You shouldn't try to change how the user interface behaviours. Use it as it is." √

Comment: okay, my problem is, that I working actual with placeholders.but if you type something , the placeholders disappear and later, you don't know directly, for what the textfield was, because the placeholder is not visible. do you know what i mean?

Comment: But this is not a OS X Solution

Comment: Put a label to the leading side of the text field, outside of it. (The "leading" side is the left side for left-to-right languages.) That's the normal way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by many ways. Simplest solution would be to start the textfield text with an offset. Place a textfield with place holder Start on it. Then place another textfield on top of it. Make the second textfield transparent and subclass UITextField.

class TextField: UITextField {

```
let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 40, bottom: 0, right: 5);

override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
}

override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
}

override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
}
```

}

Comment: Have you searched for similar methods in NSTextField?

Comment: You should have taken the concept out of my answer.